# Scroll in UIWebView even when content can be loaded in width of webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contentsize

I have a `UIWebView` whose *size is 280 pixels* (20 padding from both sides). When I load content in webview it loads it as if webview is covering complete `width(320px)`. Due to which a scroll comes. The content is plain text, and should have come in next line. But content is taking up full `320px` size.

If a table/image comes in the content then I am ok with the horizontal scroll but not when content can is plain text.

If I make my webview size 320px it is not scrolling.

Please check the snapshot of the problem I am facing:

[image: WebView with scroll even when conntent can go in next line]

Answer (score 0):

Use this `delegate` method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
     [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.0;"];

}
```

And if you still facing issues, try to decrease the `zoom` value to be `0.9, 0.85` ... etc.

**Update:**

You can also set the `scalesPageToFit` to `YES` as follows: `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

Comment: Tried, it decreased the font size of the text, but the area occupied by the content is still the same. its still scrolling.

Comment: my bad, the content which was coming from server had this flag : width=device-width. I changed this to my webview width and its working. Thanks :)